# Torch CmdLine:text behavior is puzzling

Tags: lua, torch

I am confused about the use of torch.CmdLine:text().

The documentation says the following:

```
text(string)

Logs a custom text message.
```

My understanding is that it adds some text message to the log file and the console. I just tried the sample code provided in the documentation page.

```
cmd = torch.CmdLine()
cmd:text()
cmd:text('Training a simple network')
cmd:text()
cmd:text('Options')
cmd:option('-seed',123,'initial random seed')
cmd:option('-booloption',false,'boolean option')
cmd:option('-stroption','mystring','string option')
cmd:text()

-- parse input params
params = cmd:parse(arg)



params.rundir = cmd:string('experiment', params, {dir=true})
paths.mkdir(params.rundir)

-- create log file
cmd:log(params.rundir .. '/log', params)
```

and I got the following output in command line and in the log file:

```
[program started on Sat Sep 10 14:55:30 2016]
[command line arguments]
stroption       mystring
booloption      false
seed    123
rundir  experiment
[----------------------]
```

I am not seeing any output from calling text() method.

Could someone please help me in understanding what's happening here and the proper usage of text() method?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `:text()` does not output text automatically, it seems it is there to explain the usage of the command it is parsing. https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/CmdLine.lua You can see the text after adding `-help` to the command or executing `cmd:help()`

Comment: @BasilioGerman Thanks for your comment. I understood usage of text().

Answer (score 0):

:text(*string*) method of CmdLine will only print *string* when the script is run with `-help` argument (and also when you decide to show help to user through its :help() method).

Example:

```
th MyScript.lua -help
```